# Why does this Kotlin code behave differently to this Python code?

Tags: python, kotlin, python-requests, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to build a website crawler.
For that I need to get a login cookie.

I have written this Python code, which gets the cookie for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import sys
from getpass import getpass

uname = sys.argv[1]
passw = getpass()

login = {"values[login]": uname, "values[password]": passw}

r = requests.post("https://redacted.com/signin/", data=login)

jar = r.history[0].cookies

token = jar['redacted-token']

with open("token", mode='w') as token_file:
    token_file.write(token)
```

This code does the request with the python-requests library.

This code is written in Kotlin and should fulfill the same purpose:

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils

fun login(username: String, password: String, cookieStore: CookieStore) {
    //Initialize http client
    var httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()

    //Initialize http context
    var context = HttpClientContext.create()
    context.cookieStore = cookieStore

    //Initialize Form
    var formParams = arrayListOf<NameValuePair>()
    formParams.add(BasicNameValuePair("values[login]", username))
    formParams.add(BasicNameValuePair("values[password]", password))
    var formEntity = UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParams)

    //Initialize request
    var httppost = HttpPost("https://redacted.com/signin/")
    httppost.entity = formEntity //With form


    var response = httpclient.execute(httppost, context)


    print(EntityUtils.toString(httppost.entity))
    print(EntityUtils.toString(response.entity))

}
```

The response from the server says that the password and username are wrong.

I am confused on how this code should behave differently.

Can anyone help me fix my Kotlin code?

Comment: Try specifying Content-Type header in Python code to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` explicitly, as different content type might be required

Comment: The python code runs as intended and sends this header already.

Comment: Small unrelated tip: Prefer `val` to `var`. All of these variables can be written as `val` since they're never re-assigned.